# Configure Python 3.4 and Django on Windows Azure

Tags: python, django, azure

I have a Windows Azure website that has Python 3.4 setup in the admin console.  Here is the web.config:

```
<configuration>
<appSettings>
    <add key="pythonpath" value="D:\home\site\wwwroot\mysite;D:\home\site\wwwroot\site-packages" />
    <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()" />
    <add key="DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE" value="core.settings" />   
</appSettings>
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <add name="Python_FastCGI"
            path="handler.fcgi"
            verb="*"
            modules="FastCgiModule"
            scriptProcessor="D:\Python34\python.exe|D:\Python34\Scripts\wfastcgi.py"
            resourceType="Either"
            requireAccess="Script" />
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Django Application" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="handler.fcgi/{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Everything works fine when the scriptProcessor attribute of the fastCGI config is set to use d:\Python27, but it does not work for d:\Python34.  I have used python 2.7 to verify that the files D:\Python34\python.exe and D:\Python34\Scripts\wfastcgi.py do in fact exist on the server.

**Edit:**

Just to clarify, the server returns

```
The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.
```

When checking the detailed logs it shows a generic 500 internal server error message pointing it's finger at FastCgiModule.

Comment: Asking how to run Django on Azure is like asking how to bake a delicious cake while riding a unicycle. Sure, it can be done, and it will probably look cool while your doing it, but do you really want to do that day in/day out? The sad truth is that Django on Windows (and hence azure) is a second class citizen.

Comment: @drz will you able run python34 in azure, because getting same problem for me while running fine with python27

Comment: I never did get it to work, but I gave up after a few days.  Maybe someone should start a bounty.

Answer (score 1):

Your web.config looks ok. (But you probably want to enable appendQueryString="true").

Enable logging in the azure portal and temporary enable DEBUG=True in your django project. Head over to D:\home\LogFiles\ too see what's behind that generic 500 message.

Fact that you get that generic 500 error is a sign that you are running django. You could also look if the python process is running at https://.scm.azurewebsites.net process explorer.